# Angular not working with Restful webservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, partial-views

I am developing an app and it uses restful web service on the back end and angularJS on the front. I have tested the back end for the CRUD operations using postman API client and it works fine. I have also tested the Add and View operations writing a small sized HTML code with angular, and it also works fine. My problem is that what I did in this so called "small sized HTML" is not working in my real app. Can any one help me out revealing what I did wrong. Thanks!

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'specificProductControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/list', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/list.html',
    controller: 'ListController'
  }).
  when('/details/:itemId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  }).
  when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
  }).
  when('/specificProductOrServiceAdd', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/specificProductOrServiceAdd.html',
    controller: 'SpecificProductOrServiceAddController'
  }).
  when('/adminPage', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/adminPage.html',
    controller: 'AdminPageController'
  }).
  when('/specificProducts', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/specificProducts.html',
    controller: 'SpecificProductsController'
  }).
  when('/specificProducts/:itemId', {
    templateUrl: 'partials/specificProductOrServiceDetail.html',
    controller: 'SpecificProductOrServiceDetailController'
  }).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/list'
  });
}]);
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="col-sm-12 containerr">
      <br><br>
      {{2+4}}<br><br>
        <!--The form goes here -->
      <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <br><br>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Specific Product/Service Id:</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specificProductId1" name="name" placeholder="Id" type="text" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <br><br>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Specific Product/Service Name:</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specificProductName" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="text" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Specific Product/Service Price:</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specificProductPrice" name="name" placeholder="Price" type="text" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Manufacturer/Service Provider Name:</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specificProductManufacturerName" name="name" placeholder="Provider Name" type="text" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Specific Product/Service Model (If there is):</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specificProductModel" placeholder="Model" type="text" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label for="sel1"><h4>Availablity:</h4></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select class="form-control" >
          <option>Available</option>
          <option>Not Available</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label><h4>Enter Specific Product/Service Description:</h4> </label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="name" ng-model="specificProduct.specifcProductDescription" name="name" placeholder="Description" type="text" required></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
    <a href="#/specificProducts"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addSpecificProduct(specificProduct)">+Add</button></a>
  </div>
</section>
```

```js
var specificProductControllers = angular.module('specificProductControllers', ['ngAnimate']);

specificProductControllers.controller('SpecificProductOrServiceAddController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/marketServerNew/webapi/specificProduct/spv/sp5').success(function(data) {
        $scope.readSpecificProduct = data;
      })

    $scope.addSpecificProduct = function(specificProduct) {
        $http.post("http://localhost:8080/marketServerNew/webapi/specificProduct/spa", specificProduct).success(function(data) {
            $scope.specificProduct = data;
          })
    }
}]);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>My Website</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/custom.css">
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    
</head>
<body>
<div class="main" ng-view></div>

<script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "small sized HTML"

Comment: Also, in your realtime app, I hope you would have changed your `http://localhost:8080/` occurrences to your server name.

Comment: Well, it is a form to receive some input and has a button to add it to database. It also reads one of the records from one of the tables in the database and loads it at startup.

Comment: The server I used is the same server. In my localhost! What I called my real app is different from the small sized HTML in that it has CSS, Bootstrap, and javascript modules if that helps.

Comment: Okay. Did you check your developer console for errors?

Comment: I found this - "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.9/ng/areq?p0=LoginController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135276/discussion-between-david-r-and-dejazmach).

Comment: That error basically means `LoginController` is missing from your js files but is required by one of the routes (`/login` to be precise). Validate your controller name and verify it is present in the index.html scripts.

Comment: But, I just didn't post that here as posting every controller would make the question lengthy. By the way, if it is so, then it should not affect the loading of "partials/specificProductOrServiceAdd.html" and it hasn't been affecting it while I was working only on the front end. The problem happened when integrating with the back end.

Answer (score 0):

In your get request you're still pointing to local host. Assuming you're hosting somewhere that would need to be replaced

Comment: Do you have this in plunkr or js fiddle?

Comment: Nope, but I have posted everything necessary, I think.

Comment: I'm just going off of chrome pointing out the error. In the example posted your head section is not being included. If you check your chrome console and scroll up to head, you'll be able to see it blank. Its why we're getting angular is not defined.